# Prevent JSHint's " 'a' is defined but never used. " for unused function parameters having following parameters?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

```
// jshint unused:strict

var myFunc = function(a, b, c)
{
    return b+c; // a not used => JSHint warning: 'a' is defined but never used.
};
```

Is there a way to disable or circumvent the warning for **parameters having following parameters** (in the sample above for `a` and `b`)?

For **unused last parameters** I always comment the parameters out (or remove them).

This isn't possible for **unused first parameters** in JavaScript without using `arguments`, or is it in some kind of way?

I guess the only option that makes sense is to disable the warning for all function parameters by changing `unused:strict` to `unused:vars` (global or locally around the function)?

Comment: Juts change `unused:strict` to `unused:true` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@GOTO0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083663/goto-0) already commented, you can use

`unused:true`

to get exactly the wanted behavior.

Source: [JSHint Options Reference](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#unused)